# What is (are) the best action verb(s) for a rule and program?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a code that has business objects such as "rule", "rule set" and "program". A *program* has got one of more *rule sets*, and each *rule set* has zero or more *rules*. A *program* is a client-reward program which gives rewards to clients if they do the actions that are specified by the *rules* of the *rule sets*. Each *rule set* gives a reward when all of its *rules* are done, and the whole *program* is considered done when all *rule sets* are done.

I use the word "done" here because my question is, in your opinion, what word(s) would fit the best to say that a *rule*, a *rule set* and a *program* is "done"? Fulfilled? Completed? Achieved? Done?

Comment: Maybe "earned" is the word you want--they're earned the reward(s) when they finish the rule sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting different words to indicate degrees of achievement at each level of the program, then this may work:

Rule done - could be "done" or "accomplished"

Rule set done - could be "finished" or "achieved"

Program done - could be "completed"

Comment: thanks! What if I need to use only one word for all business objects, what could work?

Comment: I would say completed, but I'm not sure of the exact "feel" you are looking for in business.